# Animate react component on idle to float from left to right and stop on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I'm mainly FE guy but came to the tough nut, I was asked to animate one react component which on idle when nothing is happening on the screen after 10 sec starts to move slowly from left to right, and upon some action in the keyboard to slowly head towards the center of the page. Does anybody had experience with this in react or CSS animations or has some advice on how to pull it off. 
Movement is something like this. But how to make it to go towards the center and stop once its there on hover on keyboard press or some other action.

Thanks.